# C# Excel VSTO - Possible to move a pivottable?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, paste, pivot-table

I am trying to move a PivotTable in VSTO and not succeeding at all. My logic was to find the range of the pivot table, cut it and paste it into a new range where i am sure that no data exists on the worksheet.

```
    public static void MovePivotTable(string sheetName, PivotTable pivotTable, int newX, int newY, int width, int height)
    {
        try
        {
            Worksheet worksheet = GetOrCreateWorksheet(sheetName);

            Range topLeft = (Range)worksheet.Cells[newX, newY];
            Range bottomRight = (Range)worksheet.Cells[newX + width, newY + height];
            Range newRange = worksheet.get_Range(topLeft, bottomRight);

            pivotTable.TableRange1.Cut(Missing.Value);

            newRange.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteAll, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone,
                Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

            return;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

However I always get an exception. Either:
- PasteSpecial has failed.
- Something along the lines that it is impossible to modify a pivot table.

Has anyone ever done this? Can they confirm that this is indeed possible or not? Any sample code?

Many thanks,
Sean

Comment: what library are you using to manipulate excel sheet?

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

TableRange1 doesn't include the Pivot Table's header, so that's why you're getting the "Can't Modify" error.  Use TableRange2 to select the whole Pivot Table.

Also, you can't do a PasteSpecial on a Cut, so just use the Destination argument of the Cut method.  This is how it would look in VB:

```
pivotTable.TableRange2.Cut Destination:=NewRange
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it still crashes with the same error. Tried doing a range.cut(destination), range.copy(missing) + range.delete(missing) + worksheet.paste(newRange) and still no luck.

Comment: You don't say so, but I assume you also tried TableRange2.  I'd try it with a simple range, like "Activesheet.Range("A1")".  Also, you listed two errors in your original question.  Please be more specific.

Comment: I had tried a wide array of solutions to this problem and throughout the testing, i stumpled upon the "impossible to modify a pivot table". that one happened once and i don't quite recall how to repropduce it but i recall the message was along those lines. the second error is the "method cut of object failed". Again, i am pretty suer that this is the error message (it appears in french so that is correct translation from the english message i believe). Finally, I did try TableRange2 without success. I'll try with a simple range like you suggest