# How to Move a NamedRange in Excel - VSTO not VBA

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, named-ranges

I've trawled the web and according to the documentation there doesn't appear to be a method to move a NamedRange: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange_methods(v=vs.80).aspx

I have the following code that copies cell data down a couple of rows:

```
activeSheet.Range[leftColumn + startRow, rightColumn + endRow].Copy();
//activeSheet.Range[leftColumn + startRow, rightColumn + endRow].Delete();
Range newRange = activeSheet.get_Range(leftColumn + (startRow + RowsToMoveDown.Count), rightColumn + (endRow + RowsToMoveDown.Count));
newRange.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteAll, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

The NamedRange is the cells I'm copying and pasting, it does move the cell values down a couple of rows but because its a Copy it leaves the data in the above cells and the Delete method causes an Exception. However the real problem is after I move the cells the NamedRange I created:

```
rnArea = activeSheet.Range[leftColumn + startRow , rightColumn + (MyData.Values.Length + startRow)];
Name name = activeBook.Names.Add(uniqueName, rnArea);
```

Still refers to the original Cells Range (the location before I the moved the cells down).

**How can I programmatically move a NamedRange in C# VSTO 4.0?**

*Ideally I wont have to move the cells before I put them in a Range but if this is the only solution, then I'll have to go with it.*

**EDIT:**

After reading Doug Glancy's comment about trying the VBA like syntax in VSTO C# I came up with the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < activeWorkbook.Names.Count; i++)
{
name = activeWorkbook.Names.Item(i + 1);
Debug.Write(name.Name.ToString());

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(name.RefersTo.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
//prints out "Sheet1!$A$1:$A$25"
name.RefersTo = "Sheet1!$A$2:$A$26";
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(name.RefersTo.ToString());
//prints out "Sheet1!$A$2:$A$26"
}
```

But when I run this code and change the NamedRange RefersTo value, the result is that the NamedRange goes missing from the Excel NamedRange DropDownList?!?!

Comment: Doubt this helps, but I thought I'd mention it: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=21749

Comment: For clarification, is the goal to cut and paste, with the named range following the cells to their new location?

Comment: yes Doug, as if you select a NamedRange from the DropDownList in Excel, it will Select the NamedRange Area and you can drag/drop the area with your mouse and it Moves the cells and also the NamedRange.

Comment: It should be `name.RefersTo ="=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$26";`.  You're missing the "=" inside the parens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "move" a named range by adding it again with a different address.  For example, in VBA:

```
Sub MoveNamedRange()
ActiveSheet.Names.Add Name:="test", RefersTo:="=$A$1"
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("test").Address
ActiveSheet.Names.Add Name:="test", RefersTo:="=$A$2"
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("test").Address
End Sub
```

This compiles and runs and yields the following in the immediate window:

```
$A$1
$A$2
```

EDIT - C is hard!  But I managed to cobble this together in VS 2010 C#.  It's from a Workbook project, but would also work in an addin I believe.  I don't think I needed all the Type.Missing's in VS 2010, but I'm pretty sure I've read they are needed in earlier versions:

```
private void Sheet1_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Globals.Sheet1.Names.Add("test", Globals.Sheet1.Range["A1"], System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);
            MessageBox.Show(Globals.Sheet1.Range["test"].Address);
            Globals.Sheet1.Names.Add("test", Globals.Sheet1.Range["A2"], System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);
            MessageBox.Show(Globals.Sheet1.Range["test"].Address);
        }
```

Comment: Hey Doug, I saw your other post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564738/c-sharp-excel-vsto-possible-to-move-a-pivottable and unfortunately this is Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) not VBA code. Your answer is exactly what I am trying to do in VSTO. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I know it is and you can do the same thing in C# VSTO.  Did you try it?

Comment: Ok + 1 that is a very valuable tip (about tryin equivilent of VBA in VSTO C#). I've seen your edit, please see my edit, I tried but got some messed up results. I would have expected it to work too. ps if VB is more your thing simply use a http://www.CodeChanger.com

Comment: OK I tried your Edit and that works perfectly. Thank you very much.